# Pipe file contents to command, and continue with user input

Tags: powershell

Can I pipe the contents of a file (or really anything) to any command and when the file ends, continue with input from me?

The command I'm thinking of takes many lines of input from stdin. I wish to provide the first few lines from a file and the continue with writing the input myself in the terminal.

Comment: you can have as many stages as you want. just save each stage into a $Var to be used in later parts of your code.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'm not writing a script; I'm just calling a command of some program on my computer. So maybe "input from the **user**" was the wrong word, because it's going to be input from **me**.

Comment: Does the command in question take input from the pipeline?

Comment: @WalterMitty I'm not 100% sure about the terminology. The command reads multiple lines from stdin. `Get-Content .\file | command` works, but when command has read all the lines in `.\file` I want to be prompted for input.

Comment: you have described a loop. take a look at `do/until`, `do/while`, and `while` loops for some fairly direct ways to do what you seem to want.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I ideally would have wanted some one-liner to use from the terminal. I wrote a script for it and posted that as an answer.

Comment: @Netråm - kool! glad to know that you got it working as you want ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a script for what I wanted. Here is a condensed version of it:

```
# Named Join-With
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [String]
    $OriginalInput
)
process {
    Write-Output $OriginalInput
}
end {
    while ($true) {
        Read-Host | Write-Output
    }
}
```

And a usage example, `Get-Content .\file | Join-With | command`. This first pipes the content of `.\file` to the `command`, and then take further input from the user.

I wrote a more comprehensive version that can be viewed on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/89netraM/e81f56ce5a464dc93fa46bb11b8d5d7a).

Comment: Here's a one-liner version ---somewhat verbose, but no file dependency: `(gc $FilePath).ForEach({ Process { $_ | Add-content endless.txt } End { While ($True) { Read-Host | Add-content endless.txt } } })`.